# Negating a fraction but not modifying the original

Tags: c++

I have written the following class for modifying a Fraction object.

```
#include "Fraction.h"
#include "GCD.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

//Implementation of the timesEq() member function
//Performs similar operation as the *= operator on the built-in types
const Fraction & Fraction::timesEq(const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.numerator;
    denominator *= op.denominator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

const Fraction & Fraction::plusEq (const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.denominator;
    numerator += op.numerator * denominator;
    denominator *= op.denominator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

const Fraction & Fraction::minusEq (const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.denominator;
    denominator = denominator * op.denominator;
    numerator -= op.numerator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

const Fraction & Fraction::divideEq (const Fraction & op )
{
    numerator *= op.denominator;
    denominator *= op.numerator;

    simplify();  // will make sure that denominator is positive and
                 //   will invoke gcd() function to reduce fraction
                 //   as much as possible

    return (*this); // returns the object which invoked the method
}

Fraction Fraction::negate(void) const
{
    return (*this * -1);
}

void Fraction::display(void)const {
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator;
}

void Fraction::simplify(void)
{
    gcd = gcd(numerator, denominator);
    numerator /= gcd;
    denominator /= gcd;
}
```

But am having trouble with the `negate` function.
I am using the function like so: `B = A.negate()`, and as such, I cannot modify the original `A` object, but need to assign the negated object to `B`.

Right now the implementation I have is giving an error:
`Error: no operator "*" matches these operands

operand types are: const Fraction * int`

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. What needs to be changed?

Comment: If you're having trouble with the `negate` function, why did you post so many lines of code, several which have nothing to do with `negate`?

Comment: I just want to make sure there's enough information to understand my question

Comment: what does your GCD class look like.? i'm trying to build a similar program and running into issues with negative numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a constructor that takes two `int`s as arguments (if you don't, you should, and not just for the sake of my answer), do this:

```
return Fraction(-numerator, denominator);
```